# the implementation of ExpiringMemoizingSupplier's method named get

Tags: java, guava

```
public T get() {
  // Another variant of Double Checked Locking.
  //
  // We use two volatile reads.  We could reduce this to one by
  // putting our fields into a holder class, but (at least on x86)
  // the extra memory consumption and indirection are more
  // expensive than the extra volatile reads.
  long nanos = expirationNanos;
  long now = Platform.systemNanoTime();
  if (nanos == 0 || now - nanos >= 0) {
    synchronized (this) {
      if (nanos == expirationNanos) { // recheck for lost race
        T t = delegate.get();
        value = t;
        nanos = now + durationNanos;
        // In the very unlikely event that nanos is 0, set it to 1;
        // no one will notice 1 ns of tardiness.
        expirationNanos = (nanos == 0) ? 1 : nanos;
        return t;
      }
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

I don't understand where the condition of second check is "nanos == expirationNanos" instead of "nanos == 0 || now - nanos >= 0". If two threads named threadA and threadB call the get method and goes to the synchonized code at the same time,threadA obtains the lock. When threadA executes all the code and release the lock,the param expirationNanos' value is also equals to the nanos' value. ThreadB cannot return t instance directly,it also executes the code. If the condition is "nano==0 || now-nanos>=0",the situation couldnot happen.

Answer (score 0):

If the condition in the second check were `nanos == 0 || now - nanos >= 0`, it would always be true since those are local variables. Also note that when `expirationNanos` is set to `nanos`, `nanos` was previously set to to `now + durationNanos`. In other words, `nanos == expirationNanos` should *not* be true when thread B enters the synchronized block.

Comment: Although `nanos` was set to `now  + durationNanos`, expirationNanos is also set to `(nanos == 0) ? 1 : nanos`. In other words, `nanos == expirationNanos` should  be true when thread B enters the synchronized block. If `nanos == now + durationNanos; expirationNanos == (nanos == 0) ? 1 : nanos` was modified `expirationNanos == now + durationNanos;`, it would be all right.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something perhaps. Keep in mind that `nanos` is a local variable; thread B has a different value for it than thread A. `nanos == expirationNanos` should be false when thread B enters.